# Dynamic variable from string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, dynamic-variables

I am copying each line of a file to separate files, depending on the content. Each line begins with `"foo"` or `"bar"`, and I want to read the first few characters of each line and dynamically change the file name variable.

```
readfile = File.open("myfile.txt", 'r')
file_foo = File.open("file1.txt", 'w')
file_bar = File.open("file2.txt", 'w')

for line in readfile
  writefile = 'file_' + line[0..2]
  writefile.write(line)
end
file_foo.close
file_bar.close
```

This throws an error, as the variable `writefile` refers to the string `"file_foo"` or `"file_bar"`.

Suggestions for an elegant Rubyist solution? I couldn't see from the documentation how `send` method could be applied here if that is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a hash of files:

```
readfile = File.open("myfile.txt", 'r')

files = {
  'foo' => File.open("file1.txt", 'w'),
  'bar' => File.open("file2.txt", 'w')
}

for line in readfile
  files[line[0..2]].write(line)
end
files.each {|k, v| v.close}
```

Comment: @Jonathan_W: Thanks. This is a simple problem, and it calls for a simple solution.

Comment: good solution to the actual problem!

Comment: Sorry, I have to be nit-picky here. First, as I mentioned before, Ruby programmers never use `for` loops. As in, _ever_. They use methods like `each`. Second, this program will blow up if a line in the file doesn't start with 'foo' or 'bar' exactly. And third, this doesn't handle the open files properly. If the program fails anywhere, you will have 3 open files that you will need to clean up manually. Even if it _doesn't_ fail, you will still have an open file to clean up (myfile.txt). You need to be aware of these things if you want to learn Ruby.

Comment: @rickyrickyrice: I know that. It's wanted to fix the main problem in the OP's code, not start a code review. Leave those comments to the OP, not me.

Comment: The OP asked for a Rubyist solution, which is the only reason I nit-picked. Also, reading it now my comment comes off as pretty hostile, I'm sorry about that.

My last nit-pick: opening a file in 'w' mode will overwrite the file in consequent writes. You need to open it in 'a' mode.

Comment: @rickyrickyrice: I know. The point is, I just wanted to fix he problem presented in the question, not to a full code review. And if I'm sounding hostile, sorry about that :). Hard to know on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `eval`. It will take a string and evaluate it as Ruby code in the current context. So your example becomes:

```
readfile = File.open("myfile.txt", 'r')

file_foo = File.open("file1.txt", 'w')
file_bar = File.open("file2.txt", 'w')

for line in readfile
  eval('file_' + line[0..2]).write(line)
end

filefoo.close
filebar.close
```

However, you asked for a "Rubyist" approach. Using `eval` is certainly NOT a Rubyist approach. Nor is the use of `for` loops. I'll take a crack at a more Rubyist approach:

```
infile  = "myfile.txt"
foofile = "file1.txt"
barfile = "file2.txt"

def append_to_file(path, content)
  File.open(path, 'a') { |f| f << content }
end

IO.readlines(readfile).each do |line|
  case line
  when /^foo/
    append_to_file(foofile, line)
  when /^bar/
    append_to_file(barfile, line)
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, keep in mind that opening a file in write mode ('w') will overwrite the contents of the file on consequent writes. Notice in my example I used append mode ('a') instead.

Comment: thanks. Why is 'eval' not a Rubyist approach? Your first answer certainly seems more economical.

Comment: There are many perils when using `eval`. For instance, it can create BIG security vulnerabilities, and it can be nearly impossible to debug in larger systems.

Comment: Never come across case before... looks v interesting. http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/  Why would you use that as opposed to if else statements?

Comment: @Jonathan_W: Not economical at all. `eval` is probably the most inefficient single method in all of Ruby, a security hole, ugly, and overkill for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `send` because what you are trying to convert a string into is not a method but is a local variable.

From Ruby 2.1, you will be able to use `Binding#local_variable_get`.

```
for line in readfile
  writefile = binding.local_variable_get(:"file_#{line[0..2]}")
  writefile.write(line)
end
```

Comment: That seems like a very useful addition... I see the preview is out now but now the final update